# How to choose variables to include in ANCOVA

Tags: r, multiple-regression, ancova, lm

I have a data set that includes a DV (Richness or Abundance) and multiple continuous and categorical variables:

```
Distances    Richness   Abundance   Canopy      Flower      Veg         Wood        Trees       Net Tray  Vines Quality
-300         1.083      1.945910149 0.886077124 0           0.397699415 0.321750554 1.945910149 0   0      3    3
-300         1.099      2.079441542 1.345282921 0           0.785398163 0.463647609 2.564949357 1   0      3    4
-300         1.076      2.708050201 1.249045772 0           0.57963974  0.785398163 2.708050201 0   1      3    4
-300         1.036      2.48490665  1.107148718 0           0.684719203 0.321750554 2.772588722 0   1      3    4
-150         1.099      0.693147181 1.345282921 0           0.225513406 0.463647609 1.945910149 1   0      2    4
-150         1.089      2.48490665  0.991156586 0           0.57963974  0.321750554 2.197224577 2   0      3    2
-150         1.09       3.33220451  0.785398163 0.225513406 0.57963974  0.397699415 2.197224577 0   1      2    3
-150         1.086      3.044522438 0.735314453 0           0.321750554 0.174083011 2.079441542 0   1      3    3
-50          1.086      2.397895273 1.345282921 0           0.463647609 0.57963974  2.564949357 0   0      2    4
-50          1.079      3.135494216 1.047197551 0           0.568675503 0.463647609 2.397895273 0   1      4    2
-50          1.099      2.302585093 0.785398163 0           0.684719203 0.785398163 2.397895273 0   1      2    3
-50          1.096      2.833213344 1.345282921 0           0.57963974  0.321750554 2.63905733  1   1      3    3
 50          1.056      3.135494216 0.886077124 0.225513406 0.321750554 0.321750554 0.693147181 1   0      2    0
 50          1.08       3.891820298 0.886077124 0           0.321750554 0.321750554 0.693147181 1   1      1    0
 50          1.083      4.094344562 0.684719203 0           0.57963974  0.321750554 0.693147181 2   1      3    0
 50          1.069      2.63905733  0.735314453 0           0.321750554 0.397699415 0.693147181 2   1      1    0
 150         1.099      1.791759469 1.047197551 0.397699415 0.684719203 0.225513406 0.693147181 0   0      1    0
 150         1.065      3.496507561 0.684719203 0.201357921 0.684719203 0.286756552 0.693147181 1   0      1    0
 150         1.072      2.890371758 0.93774449  0           0.684719203 0.321750554 0.693147181 0   1      2    0
 150         1.046      2.995732274 0.991156586 0.141897055 0.463647609 0.321750554 0.693147181 0   1      1    0
 300         1.069      2.944438979 1.107148718 0           0.321750554 0.321750554 1.098612289 0   0      1    0
 300         1.073      3.044522438 0.886077124 0.201357921 0.57963974  0.201357921 0.693147181 0   0      1    0
 300         1.081      3.80666249  0.785398163 0           0.57963974  0.267763327 0.693147181 0   1      3    0
 300         1.001      2.833213344 0.886077124 0.321750554 0.57963974  0.57963974  0.693147181 0   1      1    0
```

I am trying to produces a regression model that will allow me to see which variables significantly affect the DV and their interactions with each other. However, I can't include all of my variables into the model with their interactions because R will not allow it, there seems to be more interactions than it likes.

What I would like to know is the best way to select which variables to include in the initial model?

Would producing a standard multiple regression with all the variables and then including those significant into the ANCOVA?

The problem I see with that is there may be variables that are not having a direct significant affect on the DV but are involved in a significant interaction with a variable that is.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.